# Large amount of database shown on the webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webform that gets the data from Microsoft Access, I built a dynamic table that has two for loops, lable control and image control. the table contain 4 columns. the problem is the stored database on Access table are too large for showing them on one web page. this is my c# code that was saved on filename.aspx.cs.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i +=4)
    {
        TableRow rw = new TableRow();
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        {
            TableCell tc1 = new TableCell();
            if (!(i == ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count % 2 == 1 && j == 3))
            {
                Label l1 = new Label();
                l1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i + j]["Activite"].ToString();
                l1.Font.Bold = true;
                Image m1 = new Image();
                m1.ImageUrl = ds.Tables[0].Rows[i + j]["Photo"].ToString();
                tc1.Controls.Add(l1);
                tc1.Controls.Add(m1);
                rw.Cells.Add(tc1);
               }
        }
            Table1.Rows.Add(rw);

    }
```

Luckily it was shown successfully on the webpage without any issues however I didn't manage to write a c# code that can do move from page'hyperlink' to page'hyperlink' with specific amount of database. (What I tried to do is:
if the cells % 8 == 0 then the following database should be stored on the second hyperlink in my case its text is "2" in other words displaying only 8 cells on one hyperlink that its navigateurl is filename.aspx each cell contain lable as well as an image. does the solution makes sense?
I was asked to not use controls nor DataGrid.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use a Repeater control? Or a DataGrid?

Comment: Yes John I was asked to build a dynamic table without using neither controls nor DataGrid/GridView.

Comment: Then that's what you should say in your question!